# jquery script to populate select list / drop down if it is Saturday, Monday or Wednesday

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a requirement to fill the select list with calender dates in format DD-MM-YYYY which i did with the following script. It populates select list with date of next 90days .

Now client  request has changed and he wants to fill the select list with dates only if it is Saturday, Monday or Wednesday.. I am not able to resolve this on i tried to modify the script but it didnot work.

Below script is working. Any help in this area is appreciated

```
<script>
$(function(){
    function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
    var date = new Date();
    var selectElement = $('<select name="dddDate" class="ddDate" >'), optionElement;
    for (var count =0; count < 90; count++){
        formattedDate = pad(date.getUTCDate()) + '-' + pad(date.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' +  date.getUTCFullYear();
        optionElement = $('<option>')
        optionElement.attr('value',formattedDate);
        optionElement.text(formattedDate);
        selectElement.append(optionElement);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() +1);
    }
    $('#ddDate').append(selectElement);
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="ddDate"> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date.getDay( ): return the day-of-the-week field of a Date. Return values are between 0 (Sunday) and 6 (Saturday).
http://jsfiddle.net/UvDEa/

```
    $(function(){
    function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
    var date = new Date();
    var selectElement = $('<select name="dddDate" class="ddDate" >'), optionElement;
    for (var count =0; count < 90; count++){
        var day = date.getUTCDay();
        if (day == 6 || day == 1 || day == 3) {
          formattedDate = pad(date.getUTCDate()) + '-' + pad(date.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' +  date.getUTCFullYear();
          optionElement = $('<option>')
          optionElement.attr('value',formattedDate);
          optionElement.text(formattedDate);
          selectElement.append(optionElement);  
        }
        date.setDate(date.getDate() +1);
    }
    $('#ddDate').append(selectElement);
    });
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you can you please modify the actual script as my brains are dead right now. I tried it is showing an empty select list

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.getUTCDay()` for this, e.g.

```
if ($.inArray(date.getUTCDay(), [6, 1, 3]) > -1) {
    // Include this date
}
```

Here `6` is Saturday, `1` is Monday and `3` is Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an if that checks on the getDay() function.

```
if( formattedDate.getDay() == 1 || formattedDate.getDay() == 3 || formattedDate.getDay() == 6)
{
    optionElement = $('<option>');
    optionElement.attr('value',formattedDate);
    optionElement.text(formattedDate);
    selectElement.append(optionElement);
}
```

EDIT:

```
$(function(){
function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
var date = new Date();
var selectElement = $('<select name="dddDate" class="ddDate" >'), optionElement;
for (var count =0; count < 90; count++){
    formattedDate = pad(date.getUTCDate()) + '-' + pad(date.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' +  date.getUTCFullYear();
if( formattedDate.getDay() == 1 || formattedDate.getDay() == 3 || formattedDate.getDay() == 6)
{
    optionElement = $('<option>');
    optionElement.attr('value',formattedDate);
    optionElement.text(formattedDate);
    selectElement.append(optionElement);
 }
    date.setDate(date.getDate() +1);
}
$('#ddDate').append(selectElement);
```

});

Comment: Doesn't work show nothing... I mean select list doesn't show up

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$(function(){
function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
var date = new Date();
var selectElement = $('<select name="dddDate" class="ddDate" >'), optionElement;
for (var count =0; count < 90; count++){
    formattedDate = pad(date.getUTCDate()) + '-' + pad(date.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' +  date.getUTCFullYear();
if( date.getUTCDay() == 1 || date.getUTCDay() == 3 || date.getUTCDay() == 6)
{
    optionElement = $('<option>');
    optionElement.attr('value',formattedDate);
    optionElement.text(formattedDate);
    selectElement.append(optionElement);
 }
    date.setDate(date.getDate() +1);
}
$('#ddDate').append(selectElement);
```